# Saving an Array<Color>

Tags: swift, variables

I have an array that needs to be formatted as Array. I use the code below to save it throughout my program.

```
var ScheduledStatusD:Array<Color> {
    get {
        // Get the standard UserDefaults as "defaults"
        let defaults = UserDefaults.standard

      return defaults.stringArray(forKey: "ScheduledStatusD") ?? [Color.gray]
    }
    set (newValue) {
        // Get the standard UserDefaults as "defaults"
        let defaults = UserDefaults.standard

        defaults.set(newValue, forKey: "ScheduledStatusD")
    }
}
```

My problem is as followed:

```
Cannot convert value of type '[String]?' to expected argument type '[Color]?'
```

I've tried change the text `.stringArray` to `.array` or `.mutableArray`, but more problems arose from that. Any solutions?

FYI, the goal here is to have a dynamically stored color array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Color` cannot be saved (directly) in `UserDefaults` because it's not Property List compliant.

But it has a `description` property and can be initialized by a string.

So you could map the colors to `String` and vice versa.

And please name properties with starting lowercase letter

```
var scheduledStatusD:Array<Color> {
    get {
        return UserDefaults.standard.stringArray(forKey: "ScheduledStatusD")?
            .map{Color($0)} ?? [Color.gray]
    }
    set {
        UserDefaults.standard.set(newValue.map(\.description), forKey: "ScheduledStatusD")
    }
}
```

Comment: I found another way of going about it, but marked this as correct because it works. I ended up doing the traditional Array<String>, and instead of Color.gray, when using foreach, I did Color("\(scheduledStatusD)"). Then just set a color with each name in the Assets. A little inefficient because I have to create colors for each option, but there were only 3 total dynamic options in my case. Hope this helps.